# Session is not expiring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-membership

Probably my question is stupid but it is driving me crazy, you see I have this application its session is not expiring after logging out even though I have used Session.Abandon(), Session.Clear(), and Session.Removeall(). I have been searching all over the internet but no luck so far and I really wish I can get some help. Say I have user X if I do the following any one can login with X's account:

1- Login with X's username and password. 
2- Take Session ".ASPXFORMSAUTH" info. 
3- Logout from X's account 
4- Add the Session ".ASPXFORMSAUTH" with its value using fire fox "add cookie function" for example. 
5- type the URL and click enter 
the page just opens up and it is really driving me CRAZY!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of sessions are you using? InProc? SqlServer? Something else?

Comment: Does the SESSIONID stays the same before and after the 'logout'?

Comment: And does the page show with the _same_ SessionId ? I would expect a new session silently started.

Comment: I believe SESSIONID stays the sams since if I add the cookie with its value using fire fox add cookie session it just logs me in...

Comment: it shows the same user name I have logged in with...

Comment: Do you maybe have code somewhere, like in Global.asax, that is recreating the sesssion on Application_Start or something?

Comment: Application_Start is totally empty

Comment: guys I have checked and the SessionID is changing... but still it logs me in, please any ideas?

Comment: Please provide some code and relevant web.config sections. Something went horribly wrong.

Comment: in the 

LoginStatus1_LoggedOut event I have written the following

 

Context.Session.Clear();

Context.Session.RemoveAll();

Context.Session.Abandon();


FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

Session.Abandon();


FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();

 

and in the Session_End

 


Session.Abandon();


Session.RemoveAll();



FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

Comment: web.config: authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/mylogin.aspx"  />
  </authentication>

Answer (score 0):

You also need to call FormsAuthentication.SignOut()

Comment: I have been calling Session.RemoveAll(), Session.Abandon() and FormsAuthentication.Signout() all days but the issue still exists... :(

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you have an additional flag in Session (like "ACtive") which can be set to false during logout. Based on this, you can rediect the user to login or any other general page you want to..

I am not sure if there is defined way to handle this, but I would do something like I said.

Scenario where the user is already logged out by using FormsAuthentication.Signout() and is trying to hack the system by using the same cookie (he somehow got access to it) to access a authenticated part of the website. 
In such a scenario recommendations from Microsoft also suggests to use a persistence mechanism to log / track the user signout and use the information to redirect him to login page (and clear cookie again) in subsequent fake requests.

[Reference:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) Read bulleted point 3 in Remarks section

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking of something like this but since I am using ASP.net membership provider I thought that there is an easier way.

Comment: -1 That is bad idea. Use FormsAuthentication methods instead.

Comment: I have been using FormsAuthentication.Signout() but still when add the cookie again it can authenticate...

Comment: Even Microsoft recommends this method of tracking the logout in a medium (like said in Session / in DB) when the user logs out. Even though one calls Forms Authentication signout, the user as long as access to the cookie can forge FormsAuthentication unless you persist / track a user logout and validate it.

Comment: Tomas, you did not read the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257922/session-is-not-expiring/7262346#7262346, did you?

Comment: is this a link for my own question?

Comment: its a link for Tomas to see the answer and comments of TheGeekYouNeed